# Reachable area by traveling time

Tags: gis, openstreetmap

I would like to provide a feature to show the area one can reach in X minutes given the starting point, in real time. One can travel by car, or foot. (or even by transit)

Similar to the following services:

- https://app.traveltimeplatform.com/#
- https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/request-isoline.html

However, I do not need it to be exact, an estimation with rough polygon serves the purpose. The goal is to provide a better approach then showing a circle by distance.

I only need it for a certain country, and the data will come from OpenStreet map.

Is there a library, an algorithm, or better, an open source project I can refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *GraphHopper Routing Engine* provides an Isochrone API, which would be a good fit for this use case. Car and foot profiles are supported by the API.

Find out more about this engine:

- Demo: https://graphhopper.com/api/1/examples/#isochrone
- API Docs: https://graphhopper.com/api/1/docs/isochrone/
- Source code on Github: https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper